# How to add data to a table dynamically only in html page, like in my sample image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

[image]

I want to add data to the table only for visual purpose , so that i need to add the user input from those four fields (2 drop-downs selections , and 2 user inputs),by clicking add button, without refreshing the page. (on the fly).No server call included , just for the html page

Comment: Had you tried it with ajax?

Comment: no ! i just need to insert data to the table using javascript (inserting elements ) or something only for html page, finally there is a save button where all data inserted is going to send to the back end.

Comment: Post your html here. So I can help you

Comment: this is my code

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0ByQMZlLHHs8sbjNmUjlMMGFPZ0k/view?usp=sharing

please let me know if you having any download issues, thank you for ur help Poonam

Comment: No research, not a single line of code demonstrating your effort and / or your level of HTML knowledge

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

  $('#btnFillTable').on('click', fillTable);

});

function fillTable(){
// get values form dropdown and text boxes
var a1Value = $('#A1').val();
var a2Value = $('#A2').val();
var b1Value = $('#B1').val();
var b2Value = $('#B2').val();

var rowHtml = '<tr><td>'+a1Value +'</td><td>'+a2Value +'</td><td>'+b1Value +'</td><td>'+b2Value +'</td></tr>';

// lets suppose table id is 'tblViewRecords'

$('#tblViewRecords tbody').append(rowHtml);
  }
```

```css
#tblViewRecords th{
  text-align:left;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="A1">
  <option value="First">First</option>
  <option value="Second">Second</option>
  <option value="Third">Third</option>
</select>
<select id="A2">
    <option value="First">First</option>
  <option value="Second">Second</option>
  <option value="Third">Third</option>
</select>
<input id="B1" />
<input id="B2" />
<button type="button" id="btnFillTable">Add Entry</button>
<br>
<hr>
<table id="tblViewRecords" width="100%">
  <thead>
    <tr>
    <th>B1</th>
    <th>B2</th>
    <th>A1</th>
    <th>A2</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
  <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```

`

Comment: You have to include jQuery library into your HTML page First

Comment: Muhammad your answer is correct , thank you very much for your help , i appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do with javascript only, not a bit of jQuery then you can prefer it:

```js
function myFunction() {
    var table = document.getElementById("myTable");
    var rowCount = table.rows.length;
    var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);
  
    var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
    var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
    var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
    var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);

    var branchA1 = document.getElementById("branchA1").value;
    var branchA2 = document.getElementById("branchA2").value;
    var BoxID = document.getElementById("BoxID").value;
    var OurID = document.getElementById("OurID").value;
    cell1.innerHTML = BoxID;
    cell2.innerHTML = OurID;
    cell3.innerHTML = branchA1;
    cell4.innerHTML = branchA2;
}
```

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
  <head>
      
  </head>
  <body>

     <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-7"> 
                    <div class="well">
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="exampleInputEmail1">A1</label>
                                    <select name="branchID" class="form-control" id="branchA1">
                                        <option value="PB/001">A1</option>
                                        <option value="PB/002">A1_1</option>
                                    </select>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="exampleInputEmail1">A2</label>
                                    <select name="branchID" class="form-control" id="branchA2">
                                        <option value="PB/001">A2</option>
                                        <option value="PB/002">A2_1</option>
                                    </select>
                            </div>
                        </div>    
                    </div>    
                </div>  

                <div class="col-md-5">    
                    <div class="well">

                        
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

                <div class="well">
                    
                        <form class="form-horizontal">
                            <p>
                                    <div class="col-md-5">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label class="col-md-4 control-label">B1</label>
                                            <div class="col-md-8">
                                                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Box ID"  id="BoxID"/>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-5">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label class="col-md-4 control-label">B2</label>
                                            <div class="col-md-8">
                                                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Our ID" id="OurID"/>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-2">
                                        <input type="button" value="Add_entry" onclick="myFunction()">
                                    </div>
                              </p>        
                        </form>   

                        <div class="table-responsive">
            <table class="table " id="myTable" border="1px">
                <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>DOK box ID</th>
                    <th>Our box ID</th>
                    <th>Branch</th>
                    <th>Department</th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
               
                
                </tbody>

            </table>
        </div>       

                </div>
            


            
        </form>

</body>
```